# CanopyTax scrapping with puppeteer getting timeout

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to make a simple scrapper for Canopytax with puppeteer. Here I can login to canopytax but after that when I try to go the payment url it is getting navigation timeout.
This is the sample error:

```
TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 60000 ms exceeded
at new Deferred (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/util/Deferred.ts:73:28)
at Function.create (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/util/Deferred.ts:29:12)
at new LifecycleWatcher (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/cdp/LifecycleWatcher.ts:170:42)
at CdpFrame.goto (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/cdp/Frame.ts:140:21)
at CdpFrame.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/util/decorators.ts:63:21)
at CdpPage.goto (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/api/Page.ts:1581:35)
```

This is my code:

```
const paymentUrl = 'https://app.canopytax.com/#/billing/payments/collected';
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
                ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            });

            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
            await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
            await page.goto(websiteUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

            await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
            await page.keyboard.type(C.username);
            await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
            await page.keyboard.type(C.password);
            await page.click(CTA_SELECTOR);
            await page.waitForNavigation();
            await page.click(OTP_NEXT_SELECTOR);
            await page.waitForNetworkIdle();
            await sleep(50000);
            const otp = await this.getOtpFromEmail();
            await page.click(OTP_INPUT_SELECTOR);
            await page.keyboard.type(otp);
            await page.click(OTP_NEXT_SELECTOR);
            console.log('OTP Submitted');
            await sleep(4000);
            await page.goto(paymentUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

            await browser.close();
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please share all of your code. `USERNAME_SELECTOR`, `getOtpFromEmail` and so forth are undefined. [`await page.waitForNavigation();` looks like a race condition](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation).